# Issue when Building OpenCV.js

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, opencv

I can't build OpenCV.js using this instructions: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da1/tutorial_js_setup.html

I'm currently running this on Windows but have tried on a Ubuntu VM and have run into the same issues.

When I try to execute:

`python ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_js`

I run into errors. I've tried multiple different approaches, including:

`python ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_js emscripten_dir=/c/John/Downloads/emsdk/upstream/emscripten`

and receive the following error in Git Bash:

```
Check dir C:\Users\John\Downloads\cv-setup\emsdk\opencv\build_js (create: True, clean: False)
Check dir C:\Users\John\Downloads\cv-setup\emsdk\opencv (create: False, clean: False)
Check dir C:\Program Files\Git\Users\John\Downloads\cv-setup\emsdk\upstream\emscripten (create: False, clean: False)
=====
===== Config OpenCV.js build for default target
=====
Executing: ['cmake', '-DENABLE_PIC=FALSE', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE='C:\\Program Files\\Git\\Users\\John\\Downloads\\cv-setup\\emsdk\\upstream\\emscripten\\cmake\\Modules\\Platform\\Emscripten.cmake'", "-DCPU_BASELINE=''", "-DCPU_DISPATCH=''", '-DCV_TRACE=OFF', '-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF', '-DWITH_1394=OFF', '-DWITH_ADE=OFF', '-DWITH_VTK=OFF', '-DWITH_EIGEN=OFF', '-DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF', '-DWITH_GSTREAMER=OFF', '-DWITH_GTK=OFF', '-DWITH_GTK_2_X=OFF', '-DWITH_IPP=OFF', '-DWITH_JASPER=OFF', '-DWITH_JPEG=OFF', '-DWITH_WEBP=OFF', '-DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF', '-DWITH_OPENGL=OFF', '-DWITH_OPENVX=OFF', '-DWITH_OPENNI=OFF', '-DWITH_OPENNI2=OFF', '-DWITH_PNG=OFF', '-DWITH_TBB=OFF', '-DWITH_TIFF=OFF', '-DWITH_V4L=OFF', '-DWITH_OPENCL=OFF', '-DWITH_OPENCL_SVM=OFF', '-DWITH_OPENCLAMDFFT=OFF', '-DWITH_OPENCLAMDBLAS=OFF', '-DWITH_GPHOTO2=OFF', '-DWITH_LAPACK=OFF', '-DWITH_ITT=OFF', '-DWITH_QUIRC=OFF', '-DBUILD_ZLIB=ON', '-DBUILD_opencv_apps=OFF', '-DBUILD_opencv_calib3d=ON', '-DBUILD_opencv_dnn=ON', '-DBUILD_opencv_features2d=ON', '-DBUILD_opencv_flann=ON', '-DBUILD_opencv_gapi=OFF', '-DBUILD_opencv_ml=OFF', '-DBUILD_opencv_photo=ON', '-DBUILD_opencv_imgcodecs=OFF', '-DBUILD_opencv_shape=OFF', '-DBUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF', '-DBUILD_opencv_videostab=OFF', '-DBUILD_opencv_highgui=OFF', '-DBUILD_opencv_superres=OFF', '-DBUILD_opencv_stitching=OFF', '-DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF', '-DBUILD_opencv_java_bindings_generator=OFF', '-DBUILD_opencv_js=ON', '-DBUILD_opencv_python2=OFF', '-DBUILD_opencv_python3=OFF', '-DBUILD_opencv_python_bindings_generator=OFF', '-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF', '-DBUILD_PACKAGE=OFF', '-DBUILD_TESTS=OFF', '-DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF', '-DBUILD_DOCS=OFF', '-DWITH_PTHREADS_PF=OFF', '-DCV_ENABLE_INTRINSICS=OFF', '-DBUILD_WASM_INTRIN_TESTS=OFF', "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS='-s USE_PTHREADS=0 '", "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-s USE_PTHREADS=0 '", 'C:\\Users\\John\\Downloads\\cv-setup\\emsdk\\opencv']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./platforms/js/build_js.py", line 19, in execute
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 340, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./platforms/js/build_js.py", line 269, in <module>
  File "./platforms/js/build_js.py", line 192, in config
  File "./platforms/js/build_js.py", line 25, in execute
__main__.Fail: Execution failed: 2 / The system cannot find the file specified
```

Any help is much appreciated.